# how to divide time in hours and minutes by production in excel vba userform

Tags: excel, vba

i have to divide a number like this(45)by 5.30 and also need to convert minutes into decimal
the final result will :45/5.50 = 8.18 and its has to be done in vba excel userform

Comment: =45/5.3 but if 45 is in cell A1 and 5.3 in cell B1 then =A1/B1, then divide by 60 will be decimal fractions of an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that converts a time string expression like "5:30" to a numeric expression where the seconds are converted to decimal minutes.

```
Function SecondsToMinutes(ByVal TimeString As String) As Double
    
    Dim Fun     As Double
    Dim Sp()    As String
    
    Sp = Split(TimeString, ":")
    Fun = Val(Sp(UBound(Sp))) / 60
    If UBound(Sp) Then Fun = Fun + Val(Sp(UBound(Sp) - 1))
    SecondsToMinutes = Fun
End Function
```

You can use the number returned by the above function in calculations and assign that value to a text box in a user form. The following is syntax that would write "8.18" to TextBox1.

```
TextBox1.Value = Round(45 / SecondsToMinutes("5:30"), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *CDate*:

```
Value = Round(45 / CDate("5.30") / 24, 2)
' Value -> 8.18
```